# Why is this code breaking when I take it into Dreamweaver? The menu specifically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, web, bootstrap-4

https://codepen.io/bryant-designs/pen/NvpmLy` this is the code

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-xl navbar-light bg-faded nav-bg">
    <!-- Brand -->
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
        <img src="http://svgur.com/i/2W9.svg" width="16" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="Bryant Designs">
        ryant Designs
    </a>

    <!-- Links -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="nav-content">   
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Bryant Designs</h1>

    </div>
    <h3>What can I create for you today?</h3>
    <p>Bryant designs is a digital media agency based out of Albuquerque, NM. My name is Tyler Bryant and I own & operate Bryant Designs, I am a Digital Media Specialist with experience in web design, animation, logo design, and post production. Like me on <a href="https://www.facebook.com/bryantdesigns">Facebook</a><br><br>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvRxG.png and this is what happens when taking it into a code editor that has bootstrap linked

Comment: In the last part, you are openning a `<p>` that you never close. (probably not related)

Comment: Based on the screenshot I would question if you have the necessary JavaScript assets included.

Comment: Robert C you were right thank you!